# PHP - alternatives to variable variables

Tags: php, performance, variables

Suppose I have an object `$foo` and I have the name of one of its parameters in a string variable `$bar`.

I know that I can access the value of the parameter using `$foo->$bar`, but I heard that this is kind of bad performance-wise.

Hence my question is: is there a better way to do it?

Comment: It's only going to be a problem if you're doing this several million times per second. Short of that, it really doesn't matter and you shouldn't overthink it. That said, if performance is a concern, Step 1 is to upgrade to PHP7.

Comment: Just access the property directly?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol actually it's more a curiosity that really a need. Just wanted to know if there was a better way to do it

Comment: @Dale the name of the property is in $bar and I don't know it's value, so I can't call it directly

Comment: In that case, no, I (at least) can't think of another way, and personally I agree with @NiettheDarkAbsol

Comment: some say micro optimization is evil

Answer (score 2):

First, I should say that I agree with the sentiment elsewhere on this post that it's probably not a kind of optimization that is worth your time. However, I love SO for it's facilitation of curiosity. In service of this curiosity, I wrote a small benchmarking program to compare `$foo->$bar` with the first alternative that came to mind: `$foo->someKnownArrayProperty[$bar]`. Turns out the first is consistently faster by about 10%. I tested several runs at 1M iterations, then a couple at 10M. Here is my VERY rudimentary code:

```
<?php
$iterations = 10000000;
$bar = 'someproperty';
class Foo {

}
$foo = new Foo();
$start = microtime(TRUE);
for($i = 0; $i<$iterations; $i++) {
  $rand = rand(1,1000);
  $foo->$bar = $rand;
  if($foo->$bar != $rand) {
    throw new Exception("A problem occurred reading or writing $bar");
  }
}
$end = microtime(TRUE);
$varproptime = $end - $start;
unset($foo);
$foo = new Foo();
$start = microtime(TRUE);

$foo->myarray = array();
for($i = 0; $i<$iterations; $i++) {
  $rand = rand(1,1000);
  $foo->myarray[$bar] = $rand;
  if($foo->myarray[$bar] != $rand) {
    throw new Exception("A problem occurred reading or writing $bar");
  }
}
$end = microtime(TRUE);
$arrayproptime = $end - $start;
printf("Variable Property: %f.4\nArray Property: %f.4\n", $varproptime, $arrayproptime);
```

In general, I was getting about 1.0 and 1.1 seconds for 1M iterations, and 10 and 11 seconds for 10M.

## edit

I went a bit further with another idea: Could we 'compile' a class with a 'native' property, along with a setter & getter. It's just another idea that popped in my head. It turned out to be terrible for performance, I imagine because we need add a frame to the stack (using setters and getters instead of direct access). The reason I needed to add them was that the goal if this idea was to allow all of the code to be 'static' once the iteration begins. Basically I ran a class definition through `eval()`, which should leave the program in a state that is equivalent to if it were hard-coded with the property name. The idea would be valuable if, for instance, you don't know the property name at programming time, but at request time it is exactly one value and read/written many many times. I thought perhaps a longer 'start up' time could be offset if it led to a faster access pattern. But it didn't. This was about 100% slower.

```
$classDefinition = <<<EOD
class FOO {
  public \$$bar;
  function setThatThing(\$value) {
    \$this->$bar = \$value;
  }
  function getThatThing() {
    return \$this->$bar;
  }
EOD;
eval($classDefinition);
```

At execution time, that looks like this (note some `$` are escaped, some not)

```
class FOO {
  public $someproperty;
  public function setThatThing($value) {
    $this->someproperty = $value;
  }
  public function getThatThing() {
    return $this->someproperty;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't overthink it really. If the property name is dynamically generated and you don't know its value beforehand, then the only way to access it would be  `$obj->$prop`. I can't think of any reasons why this would affect performance.